# Getting the anatomy of Twitters Json response

Tags: api, twitter

I just started working with Twitter's API.
Is there a way to find out the anatomy of the returned Json for the Twitter API methods?

It seems you only have the docs for the method but nothing on the format of returned Json (or XML) that would be returned :(

Can anybody help with this? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON('string of json data');

you can inspect the contents of this object using firebug, etc.

Some older browsers require that you include this function separately: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Comment: I actually use PHP json_decode and then use var_dump but does this mean there is no way i can know before hand the anatomy of results to expect? i have to get it first and then inspect? that does not sound too useful :(

Comment: You can use the above technique to inspect the result. This information will tell you what you need to know so you can write your php accordingly.
Looking at the Twitter api documentation, it appears that an example response is provided under each request example:
eg: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the console by APIgee

https://apigee.com/episod/embed/console/dev-twitter-com?authTypeVal=oauth1#

it's also available at

https://dev.twitter.com/console

but it's often down

Answer (score 0):

[STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) includes a Twitter API console for OS X.